# Concavity/convexity of a function whose domain is a singleton set

Tags: general-topology, functions

Is a function which is defined on the singleton domain both convex and concave? This question got raised when I read the following from [here](https://mjo.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/index.php/tutorial/index/1/gop/x): "If you look at the definition of concavity, you see that every function is concave on a domain consisting of a single point!"

My guess is that convexity/concavity is trivially fulfilled for such function, since such functions are constant functions. Is there any non-trivial argument regarding the same that I am missing?

Comment: It is a trivial fact hardly requiring a  proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Yes, it is trivial and you are not missing anything.